# remove duplicated lines taking into account only two columns

Tags: linux, bash, grep, uniq

I have a file that has some duplicated lines if I take into account only the two first columns.

For example

```
2 2 7 7
1 1 3 3
1 1 4 4
1 1 5 5
1 1 6 6 
3 3 7 7
4 4 9 9
4 4 2 2
```

In this example, I have some lines that have 1 1  or 4 4 on the two first columns, for me, those ones are duplicates. In the end, I would like to have something like this:

```
2 2 7 7
1 1 3 3
3 3 7 7
4 4 9 9
```

I would like to keep only one of the rows that have the duplicated values 1 1 or 4 4

using something like this, I am able to identify which are the duplicated lines

```
 cut -f 1,2  file.txt | sort | uniq -D
```

But I am still not sure how to remove all the duplicated lines but leave only one, especially because the other two columns are different. Could you please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: May output consist of desired lines in any order? Or must the order of the input remain?

Comment: If It is possible to keep the original order is better, but if not, is not a big problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusted `awk` code from [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11941/108618):

```
<file.txt awk '!seen[$1,$2]++'
```

It works because `awk 1` prints every line and `awk 0` prints no line. We use an array that counts occurrences, taking only the first two fields into account. Postfix `++` increases the count, but the old value is used in the expression ([like in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031409/10765659)). `!` converts any non-zero value (meaning the same two fields have already been seen) into `0` and a zero value (… have not yet been seen) into `1`.

Note multi-dimensional arrays in `awk` are in fact one-dimensional arrays. `seen[$1,$2]` is equivalent to `seen[$1 SUBSEP $2]` and the default value of `SUBSEP` is implementation-defined (see the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_0)). GNU `awk` (`gawk`) uses a quite safe character `\034` (i.e. octal `034`, file separator character in ASCII). It's a nonprinting character that is unlikely to appear in an `awk` program or in most input data.

If you suspect the default value of `SUBSEP` used by your `awk` may create ambiguous string when inserted between `$1` and `$2`, then you should set `SUBSEP` to a safe value by yourself.

In general, if fields of your input data are separated strictly by a specific character, you may want to use this character as `SUBSEP`. E.g. if the field separator is the tab character then tab cannot appear in `$1` nor `$2`. Therefore `$1"\t"$2` is an unambiguous representation of `$1` and `$2` (our two indices) as a single string. Example code:

```
​<file.txt awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"; SUBSEP="\t"} !seen[$1,$2]++'
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sort:

```
sort -t ' ' -k 1,2 -u file
```

Output:

```
1 1 3 3
2 2 7 7
3 3 7 7
4 4 9 9
```

See: `man sort`

Comment: I suspect the command is portable and there is nothing specific to GNU `sort` in it. Downsides: (1) Actual sorting is unnecessary effort in this case. (2) `sort` cannot output anything until the input ends, it cannot work on the fly; but it's easy to imagine an algorithm that immediately after reading a line decides whether the line should be printed or not. // Nevertheless the command works. +1.